# Suitable window registry location for multi user application C#

Tags: c#, registry

I am making an applications that works for multiple users and use data from registry that is written by another user.
currently I am writing to HKCU. and it is not working because HKCU is local. and after it failed i tried to write on Local Machine but it has some permision issues. 
So what is the suitable location to write the registry in this scenario.
I am using following code to create to key.

`RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser;`
`RegistryKey  subKey = regKey.CreateSubKey(subKeyName);`

Comment: Can you tell us more about which users need to access which other users' data? Your application's installer could give non-admin users access to the appropriate registry key, but it seems likelier that the registry isn't the best place to store this kind of shared, writeable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read a lot about window registry and came to know that `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG` will be 
suitable in my case because 
It is common location to all user. 
Only problem with this Registry location is that u need Administrator rights to modify the key.
`RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentConfig;`
`RegistryKey subKey = regKey.CreateSubKey(subKeyName);`

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG` is just a pointer to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profile` so you have the same problem - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776168%28v=ws.10%29.aspx